# YUI Listen for a custom event generated by jquery

Tags: jquery, events, yui3

I have inherited some legacy code written with JQuery that is creating a custom event e.g. myJqueryEvent

The code I am now writing is using yui3 and I need to listen for this Jquery custom event. Is this possible and how do I enable YUI3 to recognise the jquery event?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think this is possible. You would have to use jQuery to listen for it's event and could then use YUI to process action.